# filter out item from a nested dictionary list python

Tags: python

I got this list which is given below

```
orders = [
        {
        'order_id' : 1,
         'line_items': [
                        {
                        'product_id': 2,
                        'product_name' : 'mango',
                        'note' : 'this is fruit'
                        },
    
                        {
                        'product_id':3,
                        'product_name': 'orange',
                        'note' : 'this is fruit'
                        }
                    ],
    
        },
    
        {
        'order_id' : 2,
        'line_items': [
                        {
                        'product_id': 4,
                        'product_name' : 'banana',
                        'note' : 'this is fruit'
                        }
                      ]
        },                  
    ]
```

I want to delete note key from line_items key

I have tried in many way like list comprehension like below and other way but could not solve the problem. need a help please.

```
filter_item= ['note']

new_list = [{k:v for k,v in order.items()if k['line_items']  in filter_item} for order in orders]
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: could you give an example of an expected value ?

Comment: orders = [
    {
    'order_id' : 1,
    'line_items': [
                    {
                    'product_id': 2,
                    'product_name' : 'mango',

                    },

                    {
                    'product_id':3,
                    'product_name': 'orange',

                    }
                ],
    },
    {
'order_id' : 2,
'line_items': [
                {
                'product_id': 4,
                'product_name' : 'banana',

                }
              ]
},

Comment: So basically you want to remove `orders[0]['line_items']['note']`, `orders[1]['line_items']['note']` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [nested loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_nested.asp) and the [`del` keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp).:

```
import json

orders = ...

for order in orders:
    for item in order["line_items"]:
        if "note" in item.keys():
            del item["note"]

# for pretty output
formatted_orders = json.dumps(orders, indent=2)

print(formatted_orders)
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "order_id": 1,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "mango"
      },
      {
        "product_id": 3,
        "product_name": "orange"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_id": 2,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "product_id": 4,
        "product_name": "banana"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry i want whole entire list without line_items['note'] key

Comment: @basharmd Ah okay, updated it